# How to use Script-fu to select stroke line as in the "Stroke Path" - "Stroke Line" dialog

Tags: gimp, script-fu

In Gimp 2.6 there is an "Edit" -> "Stroke Path" dialog.  Within this dialog there is a "Stroke Line" area with options for  line-width, Cap style, Join Style, Mitre limit, etc.

How would I stroke a path with the "stroke line" options from script-fu.  I couldn't find it in the procedure browser.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you mean script-Fu is about 14 subscripts like gear,star someing.
I also try to add some lines into script-fu (XXX.scm) to fix it (default path stroke is too width).

I found this url: http://www.gimptalk.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=51559

"Not possible. The only thing you can do is stroke with the active brush.

-Rob A> "

And I changed brush from default(11) to 3 , try script again, every thing is OK.

thanks Rob A

Answer (score 0):

(almost 2 years later) this is still impossible (or at least I couldn't find any solution). Obviously this won't do, so I came up with [this](https://github.com/reinhrst/nl.claude.tools/tree/master/gimp-fu).

The trick is that the plug-in saves the path as an SVG, and then imports the SVG as image again. It should kind of work in most cases, but basically has been tested as to work in my, pretty simple, case :)

(and yes, I'm kind of hacking my way through, regex-search-and-replacing XML. Probably better to do this with an xml library :))